# DHCPv6 (RFC 8415) - What are reasonable initial values for time intervals T1/T2?

Tags: dhcp, rfc, protocol, dhcpv6

As described in [Section 18.2. - Client Behavior](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-18.2) of [`DHCP - RFC 8415`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415) a client *uses the Solicit message to discover DHCP servers configured to assign leases or return other configuration parameters on the link to which the client is attached.*

As part of the Solicit message a client *uses IA_NA* (`Identity Association for Non-temporary Addresses`) *options (see [Section 21.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-21.4)) to request the assignment of non-temporary addresses* ([Section 18.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-18.2.1)).

The `Identity Association for Non-temporary Addresses Option` includes two time intervals:

> - T1 - The time interval after which the client should contact the server from which the addresses in the IA_NA were obtained to extend the lifetimes of the addresses assigned to the IA_NA; T1 is a time duration relative to the current time expressed in units of seconds. A 4-octet field containing an unsigned integer.
> - T2 - The time interval after which the client should contact any available server to extend the lifetimes of the addresses assigned to the IA_NA; T2 is a time duration relative to the current time expressed in units of seconds.  A 4-octet field containing an unsigned integer.

Although i understand what the times `T1`/`T2` represent, i could not find any information on either default values or an algorithm to set reasonable initial values. [Section 14.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-14.2) describes cases in which the value could be 0, but only on reception of an IA_NA option and not for an initial Solicit message.

---

#### 1. Are the values for `T1`/`T2` irrelevant when a client sends an initial Solicit message (so i would assume setting them to 0 is ok)?

#### 2. If they are not irrelevant, what are reasonable initial values for `T1`/`T2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that i am unable to read because i linked the exact section [21.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-21.4) that answers my questions clearly:

> In a message sent by a client to a server, the T1 and T2 fields SHOULD be set to 0. The server MUST ignore any values in these fields in messages received from a client.

Therefore...

#### 1. Are the values for `T1`/`T2` irrelevant when a client sends an initial Solicit message (so i would assume setting them to 0 is ok)?

Arguably the values are irrelevant because the server MUST ignore them anyway BUT they SHOULD be set to 0!

#### 2. If they are not irrelevant, what are reasonable initial values for `T1`/`T2`?

It is reasonable to follow the RFC that specifies the values, therefor `T1 = T2 = 0`!